# I can't get the datas from Angularjs'post request

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

codes in js file: I try to send an array data to SpingMVC

```
todelSome: function (targetArr) {

        var args = {"arr": targetArr};
        var url = "toDelSome.req";

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: args,
            url: url
        }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {


            return response;
            console.log(response);


        }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {

            alert(status + response);

        });

    }"
```

here is my SpringMVC code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("toDelSome")
public String toDelSome(@RequestParam("arr[]") Integer[] arr) {

    System.out.println(arr);

    return "";
}
```

Here are console log:
[image]
[image]

How can I get the array data from Angularjs'request ?

Comment: No, it's not that issue. I remove it, and the problem still exist.

Comment: is it that you want the method `toDelSome` to return the array?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping("toDelSome")
 public String toDelSome(@RequestParam("arr") Integer[] arr) {

 System.out.println(arr);

 return "";
}
```

Comment: The same. 400 error:Required Integer[] parameter 'arr' is not present

Comment: can you display targetArr?

Comment: You can see the snapshot I posted. I can get the targetArr in Angular request, but I can't get anything about it in SpirngMVC console, not even "NULL"

Comment: change 'arr[]' to 'arr'

Comment: The same. It's about the Angularjs request send a json data to SpringMVC, but springMVC can't resolve it. It's not as same as Ajax. And I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: do u add jackson lib or maven dependency?

Comment: may be it's not matches in java side. your array that u send it from client side match in server side.

Comment: of course, I have added Jackson databind,core,annotation jars.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I have to create a java bean  for what the Angularjs sends, so that the @RequestBody can map the attributes. But I just get a temporary data, it's no need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Going the long way create a class that takes an array,  the variable name should be arr:

```
public class MockClass{
     Object[] arr;
     public Object[] getArr() { return arr;} 
     public void setArr(Object[] arr) { this.arr = arr;} 
} 

data:{"arr": targetArr}
```

Then change `@RequestParam` to `@RequestBody MockClass mock` or try `@ModelAttribute` if RequestBody doesn't work

Comment: When I used @RequestBody, arr is NULL.  When we use Ajax, this method works well.Bnt Angularjs seems different from jquery. That's where confused me so much.

Comment: Thank you. I know your method will work well. The @RequestBody have to map a java class. But it's not convenient for a temporary data. If I have some other datas, like String[], Long[] and so on, I have to create their classes.  I want to find a way like the Jquery ajax if possible.

Comment: Use Object then spring will return the right object be it `String` `Long` whatever

Comment: I find an information about this issue:   By default, jQuery transmits data using Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded and the familiar foo=bar&baz=moe serialization. AngularJS, however, transmits data using Content-Type: application/json and { "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" } JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this way **:**

Code in js file

```
todelSome = function(targetArr) {
        var args = {arr : targetArr};
        var url = "toDelSome";

        $http.post(url, args).then( function(data, status, headers) {

            return data;
            console.log(data);

        }, function(error) {

            alert(error);

        });
    };
```

Code in controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("toDelSome")
public String toDelSome(@RequestBody Integer[] arr) {

    System.out.println(arr);

    return "";
}
```